# Use Windows CE .NET Emulator on Windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, visual-studio-2003

I am currently working with a Datalogic Scanner (Skorpio x3) and am trying to get the emulator for Windows CE working on Windows 7.

The current solution is a Windows-XP VM with Visual Studio 2003 and the included emulator.

However, I was asked to migrate the project to Windows 7 and preferably Visual Studio 2005.
Installing Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 and just start the emulator did not work.

I also tried Windows 7 & Visual Studio 2003, but this was not working either.

Deployment onto a physical device is working.

So my question is:
**Is it even possible to run the Windows CE Emulator on Windows 7?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Microsoft Platform Builder](http://www.msembedded.biz/en/embedded/windows-embedded-ce-wece/kostenlose-evaluierung/) (fullfill all requirements) and [create your own Windows CE image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms918283.aspx).